# How can we send email with an attachment to 500 people using SQL Server (SSIS, SSRS or SQL AGENT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I need your advice. How can we send email with an attachment to 500 users. We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition in our company.

I had tried using the `Send Mail` task from SSIS, but seems we can send maximum of 18 recipients due to the constraint in `To: Cc: Bcc:`.

Is there any way we can send using SQL Agent or SSRS ??

I have another doubt regarding SSRS report subscription recipients.

To how many maximum number of recipients we can send report using subscription. The reason i am asking this second is if i can send a report to 500 users by using SSRS report subscription then i can use SSRS.

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use Database Mail feature and write your own T-SQL code to send the email using [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189635%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) `@recipients` parameter you would use to pass in a delimited list is type `varchar(max)` so I am sure it can handle your 500 email address. I cannot find anything on MSDN that states a limit other than the data type limit.

I would probably stick with SQL Agent in this instance if it is going to be repeated.

**EDIT**
As suggested by Brian in the comments, you probably do want to use the `@blind_copy_recipients`, which has the same data type.

Comment: varchar(max) will sure not handle 500 emails

Comment: varchar(max) will easily handle 500 emails

Comment: Just a comment, I'd use the @blind_copy_recipients for the addresses to protect from reply all issues and hide email addresses. recipients, copy_recipients, and blind_copy recipients are all varchar(max). varchar(max) will hold roughly 2 GB. With 500 email addresses at 50 characters each + 500 semicolons to delimit each address, + the 2 bytes for being variable length, that comes out to 25502 bytes or 25 kilobytes. This is much smaller than the 2 GB limit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually SSRS would work quite nicely.  We send out about 4000-5000 emailed reports using a SSRS every few weeks.

Create a report that will produce your attachment. Create a query providing email addresses and any report parameters.  Next create a data driven subscription using your query.  You should be able to scale to thousands of recipients as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a cursor that loops thru all the recipients and send emails one recipient at a time... Even if you have never written a cursor it is not hard to do following the example in the help...